# Installing kivy on portable python

Tags: python, portability, kivy

Im trying to install kivy in my portable python with this installer:
[http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#kivy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#kivy)
(Its a pre-compiled version of kivy)

When executing the file, it says "Python 2.7 version required", but since the python version im using is portable, I guess this is normal.

So my question is, **is there a workarround to install a precompiled package in portable python?** By somehow registering the portable python installation?

More (*maybe innecesary*) information:

> My guess would be registering portable python in the system (Windows 7
> 64), but I already tried by changing the "path" enviroiment variable to point all
> the required python paths without success.
>
> I cant use the kivy modules to install it by compiling it on my computer because its too hard for me,(cython wont work, or then another of the 7 different modules will give me problems, untill i destroy my python installation. I already destroyed my
> previous python installation while doing so, and had to reinstall
> windows to get python working again -_-
>
> Thats why I want to migrate
> into portable python, but if this is not possible I will just go back
> to normal python and install kivy on it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click on the kivy.bat.

You will have a console have easy_install and pip available. Compiler is set to Mingw, and cython is already installed. Everything will be installed in the portable installation, not your system installation.

Enjoy :)

Note: if you want to see how we do, just edit the kivy.bat.

Comment: That is good but the objective here is to install kivy in portable python,since portable python has a lot of modules kivy portable python lacks of :)

Comment: I think i understood. One thing that could be missing is to make a script to register our python portable as a python portable package, and then, you could use standard installer.

Comment: Note that you can do: easy_install python-package-installer.exe, it works. (yes, exe.) No need to double-click on it.

Comment: That last comment changes everything, since then the full installation of all my packages is dead quick and easy... Thanks, setting this as the answer!

Answer (score 3):

The Kivy package on windows includes a portable python installation with Kivy installed.

Comment: Thank you Sam. Yes, I am aware of this, but then again it doesnt come with many modules that I use like PyNum and some more. My goal is to develop apps that use those modules and use kivy as the Gui, so if I use the portable version shipped with kivy I will have the inverse problem, having to install the rest of the modules in the portable python shipped with kivy.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but you might be able to move modules manually into the site-packages directory